# Retrieve the (unique) keys used by a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Is there a `data.table` idiomatic way to obtain the unique keys of a data table, when it is given as a single column?

I am working over a number of data sets, each of around 10 million rows and want to keep function calls/overhead to a minimum. With the below toy example,

```
require(data.table)
d_test<-data.table(id=c(1,1,2,7,2,3,5),
                   amt=c(100,200,400,600,231,-100,-200),
                   pay=c(-2,rep(1:3,2)),
                   key="id")
```

the output I am seeking is equivalent to, either as a vector or data.table,

`unique(d_test[,.(id)])`, or `unique(d_test$id)`

that is, `c(1,2,3,5,7)`

Comment: I guess the idiomatic way might be `unique(d_test[, key(d_test), with=FALSE])`, but for the specific case of a single-column key, your approaches and George's (in the answer below) seem fine. Note that the default of `unique.data.table` is to go `by=key(x)`. See `?unique.data.table`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way

```
k="id"
d2=unique(d_test, by=k)
set(d2, j=setdiff(names(d2),k), value=NULL)
d2
#   id
#1:  1
#2:  2
#3:  3
#4:  5
#5:  7
```

This will be easier when [#1269: *Returning only groups*](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1269) implemented.

Comment: Useful to know about the open ticket.

Comment: I'm leaving references cause github allows to subscribe to issue. Anyone can be up to date on eventual resolution. I stamp my code in such cases with ref to issue, so code can be easily updated in future to cleaner api.

Answer (score -1):

Would something like this work?

```
 d_test[,unique(get(key(d_test)))]
```

Comment: This only works for single-column keys.. moving to delete.